# Why is it forbidden to make GET requests to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs` from certain hosts?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-auth-library

When I do normal curl queries:

```bash
curl -isS https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs
```

for some reason such requests are successful from the local computer, but from the remote computer (provided to me by a known VPS hoster) for some reason they receive a 403 response:

```
Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/oauth2/v1/certs</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.
```

How can this problem be solved?